# JNI memory leak when opening file dialog from C++?

Tags: java, c++, string, java-native-interface, showdialog

**Problem: Hangs when openfiledialog is clicked.**

By right, when I click the openfiledialog button in my C++ program, it will input and ask me which file I will need to use, but now it totally hangs the moment I click the button.

Currently I have a C++ program that runs successfully in C++. So I've decided to try out JNI by Java. I imported the C++ program into a DLL, and **successfully** used java command to execute the C++ program. The whole program works, only one portion does not work, which is the openfiledialog.

I have no idea why, but I strongly believe it is part of the memory portion when the showdialog comes into place, can any experts please shed some light on this? Thanks.

C++ Code for showdialog.

```
private: System::Void btnOpen_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            vector<vector<int>> file;
            vector<int> column;
            int col = 0;
            int row = 0;

            openFileDialog->ShowDialog(); <- Does not even execute showdialog at all

            string test = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(openFileDialog->FileName); <-- I strongly suspect this part has an issue that causes the crash
            cout << test << endl;
file.open(test);
.... (does the normal appending of text into the vectors)
file.close(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the DLL i imported I did not add in the metagen as well to the relative folder, that is why it caused the error.

Thanks all :)